# How to boot from new CF card?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, embedded-linux, sudo, dd

I have  a  embedded development box  which has a CF (Compact Flash) card and it contains linux fedora 11 OS  followed by complete development code , scripts etc.

**Objective:** I need to take the image from CF present in the development box and upload this image into new CF cards so that when they are connected into new development machine they are ready to use without any need to load OS , development scripts etc.

**What I have done so far:**

1. I Have attached  Card reader into my Ubuntu machine  and  took the image from the old CF card and save it for future use.

   **Example:** `sudo dd if=/dev/sdg1 of=./backup_image.img bs=4096 , conv=sync, noerror`
   The image is saved under the name backup_image.img
2. I have taken new CF card  and attached it to reader and then `umount` it

   `sudo umount  /dev/sdg1`
3. Write zero in all blocks  into new CF

   **Example:** `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdg1`
4. Once step 3 is completed , I have copied saved image into new CF card.

   **Example:** `sudo dd if=backup_image.img of=/dev/sdg1`

**Result:** Successful.

But when I actually connected the new CF card into development machine , it failed to boot up .

I have compared lode CF and new CF and both has identical filesystems i.e ext3 and both has used exactly same bytes .

I am completely clueless like what I am missing here.

Comment: conv should have the "notrunc" option. Not sure if this is the only problem here though.

Answer (score 0):

if you have grub installed on your partition (/boot/grub) you should try to set the boot flag. You can use Gparted for that.

Otherwise you have to reinstall Grub to your first bytes of the CF (before the first partition starts). [GRUB](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB)